For stripInaccessible checks on READ operation discard unsanitized data
Salesforce does a terrible job at providing documentation for addressing errors thrown by its own tools. For example, after executing the sf scanner dfa command, we get the following error:

For stripInaccessible checks on READ operation,
Salesforce Graph Engine can't verify that only
sanitized data is used after the check. Discard
unsanitized data for [READ]

What does that mean and how we do to solve that issue?
The error is point to this line:
SObjectAccessDecision securityDecision = Security.stripInaccessible(
      AccessType.READABLE,
      [
        SELECT Id, Name, Custom_Field__c
        FROM Custom_Object__c
      ]
    );


I'm not sure how sf scanner dfa is executed in your case and what version used. I have tried 4.2.0 and 3.26.0 and inserting a run before the dfa, I get 5 columns as output: Source Location, Sink Location, Description, Category and URL. The URL for the above rule violation "Description" points to this page, explaining

The stripInaccessible warning is thrown for all stripInaccessible
checks on READ access type. Graph Engine can't ensure that the
sanitized value returned by SecurityDecision is the value used in the
code that follows the check. Confirm the values manually, then add an
engine directive to force Graph Engine to ignore this warning in the
next run. Or, disable these violations...

There is another way for clarifying rule violations reported by the scanner. Salesforce has published the source code. You will find above error message here. From there one can retrieve some comments in this file:

Represents a warning about stripInaccessible check on Read operation, which lets the developer know that SFGE doesn't have sufficient information and asks them to apply their best judgement.

There's an example too. Just in case you don't want to investigate from the code base the precise situation when this violation is fired ;-)
